# Not able to push android wearable app to samsung Gear with Android OS

Tags: wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

We are facing issue when trying to push a android wearable app to Samsung Gear with Android OS.

The below steps we have followed.

1.Copy the signed wearable app to your handheld project's res/raw directory. We'll refer to the APK as wearable_app.apk.

2.Create a res/xml/wearable_app_desc.xml file that contains the version and path information of the wearable app. For example:

```
<wearableApp package="wearable.app.package.name">
<versionCode>1</versionCode>
<versionName>1.0</versionName>
<rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId> 
</wearableApp>
```

The package, versionCode, and versionName are the same values specified in the wearable app's AndroidManifest.xml file. The rawPathResId is the static variable name of the APK resource. For example, for wearable_app.apk, the static variable name is wearable_app.

3.Add a meta-data tag to your handheld app's  tag to reference the    wearable_app_desc.xml file.

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
 android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

But after the host app is installed aon device, it  is not pushing the app to samsung gear android after connecting through bluetooth. 
Note: Please note that the same is working on other android watch devices.

Please guide me, if iam missing anything in above process, or do i need to add anything related to samsung gear android.

Answer (score 0):

wearable_app.wgt goes in the Android project in the assets folder, not res/raw.  If it's not in assets, the Gear Manager won't know to transfer the wearable app to the watch.

Comment: we are able to successfully push the Tizen app which is wearable_app.wgt by placing it in the assets folder for other Samsung Gear1 device running on Tizen OS . But the one which we are trying now is  android wearable app i.e., wearable_app.apk to Samsung Gear1 using Android Studio.

Comment: Our Samsung Gear device OS firmware version is "V700XXUBNC1" and gear manager version is 1.8.022599 which is automatically installing after pairing the gear with mobile.
We are very sure that our Samsung Gear device is currently running with android OS. Please help.

Comment: My apologies, I was referring to the Tizen app. For the Gear Live (android device), you will follow the Android Wear deployment instructions regardless of whether it's Samsung or other manufacturers.

Comment: we are using Gear1(android)device and not the Gear Live.Gear 1 is released with Android OS and now it has an update of Tizen OS. But we want to deploy the android wearable app to it.                                                    When we pair Gear1 device with Android (Samsung) handheld device, it is pushing Samsung Gear App to handheld device.Now Gear1  is connected through Samsung Gear.But when we install wearable app in handheld, it is not pushing wearable app to Gear1.Please help.

Comment: Note: Even though Gear 1 has an update of Tizen, we have not yet updated it,now it is still running on Android OS.